# Questions on AES encryption in Java using crypto library

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, java-security, javax.crypto

I was currently looking for a sample AES encryption and decryption using Java and I have stumbled upon something like this as a solution:

[LINK](https://medium.com/@danojadias/aes-256bit-encryption-decryption-and-storing-in-the-database-using-java-2ada3f2a0b14)

Other solutions offered the same approach. I managed to got it to work but I just have some questions on its implementation.

Questions:

1. Why does the PBEKeySpec class need a password? what is it for? there
   is already a key, why does it need to have an additional token or
   password?
2. I understand that the key and salt is part of the encrypted value of
   the original un-encrypted string. Why is that so? why not allow to
   store the generate key and salt somewhere else?

Thanks and I appreciate any form of help. Just want to understand why it was made that way.

Answer (score 0):

For easy-to-use and rock-solid java encryption library I recommend to use http://www.jasypt.org/

To your questions:

1. password is often used to derive the encryption key; this is needed because many algorithms require keys to meet certain properties such as length and randomness which isn't satisfied by many of the passwords normally used by people. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html
2. A salt and an initialization vector are stored *alongside* the encrypted value (that is they are NOT encrypted) because it's convenient - you can easily retrieve them and use them to decrypt the original string. This is still safe because you typically only need these values to be unique not to be kept secret; e.g. salt helps you prevent rainbow table attacks by having a unique salt for each value.
   A useful resource explaining some terminology: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/what-is-the-main-difference-between-a-key-an-iv-and-a-nonce

Comment: can you explain to me in simplest terms how the key, salt and iv work together to encrypt and decrypt? and why even if the salt and iv known, the encrypted string will not be able to be encrypted properly?

Comment: I'd suggest looking here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/what-is-the-difference-between-pbe-and-symmetric-key-encryption and perhaps ask on crypto.stackexchange since this is clearly out of scope for StackOverflow.